# How to secure APIs with Keycloak?

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, openid, keycloak

We have some APIs running on the JBoss EAP 7 and have Microsoft AD with user credentials. We are trying to do both authentication and authorization on the APIs. Do we have to use the JBoss SSO server (keycloak server)? It seems redundant to the AD server.

If we have to go to the keycloak server route, any good document with sample setup, especially on single sign on from keycloak to AD?

Answer (score 0):

when you want to secure your web ressources, you *can* use keycloak OR you will need to write your own login functionality. When you use keycloak, then you can secure your API via configuration. Probably you will not need any additional programming (but I don't know, what your requirements are). You can configure keycloak to use AD via kerberos.